# Renaming local GIT branch does not change name on 'Origin'

Tags: git, branch, rename, git-branch, bitbucket

I use GIT to manage my project's source code, using SourceTree locally and BitBucket to host the code remotely. I made a new branch, called "MyFeature." At some point I renamed the branch, say to "features/MyFeature," so that the branches would be better organized (I now have many more branches than before). However, it seems that now on BitBucket, there are two branches - "MyFeature," and "features/MyFeature." Is there a way to remove the old branch from BitBucket, so that there is only one branch, "features/MyFeature"? What is the best way to rename branches so that the branch names remain consistent across different checkouts of the GIT repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a branch from a remote, use git push:

```
git push origin :branch-to-delete
```

Users of other clones have to rebase their local branches onto the renamed branch. Unfortunately, there's no way to keep branch names in sync automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Just to note that the ":" is actually necessary.

Comment: Yes, the colon is important. Push refspecs are always `local:remote` – if local is omitted, then remote is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To rename local and remote branch I used the following commands:

```
git checkout <old_branch_name> # to switch on branch
git branch -m <new_branch_name> # to rename local branch
git push origin :<old_branch_name> # to delete old remote branch
git branch --unset-upstream # to remove tracking from old remote branch
git push --set-upstream origin <new_branch_name> # to push and create new remote branch
```